# edit the address in account dashboard in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

can anyone tell me how you edit this section of magento I'm trying to alter the prefix's T: and F: in the telephone and fax lines.

[image]

address.phtml  calls `<?php echo $this->getPrimaryBillingAddressHtml() ?>`

which is a method:

```
public function getPrimaryBillingAddressHtml()
{
    $address = $this->getCustomer()->getPrimaryBillingAddress();

    if ($address instanceof Varien_Object) {
        return $address->format('html');
    } else {
        return Mage::helper('customer')->__('You have not set a default billing address.');
    }
}
```

in class            `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Dashboard_Address`

Then I run out of ideas....I can't workout what is printing this and how to alter it....?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the admin: `system > config > (customers) customer configuration > address templates` you'll find all the templates for the address. In your particular case, you want to edit the HTML one